# how to loop to the start of the code in java

Tags: java

So basically it's a simple calculator, where you input one number and it outputs the result. Now, after the output I want it to ask you something like "Would you like to calculate again?" and if the user selects "Yes" it starts the whole code again. Since I`m a newbie, which function would I use for that?

Edit:  tried adding a break but that did not seem to work. Is it placed correctly? Not throwing an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pfandflaschen_Converter{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
        // variables
        double number1;
        double result;
        final double priceBottle = 0.25;
        final int answerYes = 1;
        final int answerNo = 2;
        int answer;
        
        do {
    lots
    of
    code
        if (answerYes != 1){
            break;
        }
        } while (answerYes == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `do-while-loop` to do your calculation at least once and keep doing more calculations as long as the while condition is met.

Comment: you could call the same method recursively. for example: 

public void calculate(){ 
      --- ur logic --
if(calculateAgain== true){
    calculate();
}

Comment: *"which function would I use for that?"* Wrong question. The question is: How would I best find out how to do that? Answer: Web search for [`java loop`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+loop) would likely find you a gazillion examples of how to write loops in Java, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Combine your do-while with method usage.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pfandflaschen_Converter{

    // variables
    private static double number1;
    private static double result;
    private static final double priceBottle = 0.25;
    private static final int answerYes = 1;      
    private static int answerNo = 2;
    private static int answer;
    
    private static void doCalculations()
    {
        // do lots of code
    }

    private static boolean getUserAnswer()
    {
        // ask user if they want to redo calculation
        // return true if yes, else false
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args){

        do
        {
            doCalculations();
        }
        while( getUserAnswer() );
     }
}
```

Comment: There is a variety of options to deal with user answers. E.g. you can map `1` to `true` which is implicit in Java, you can also let users pass an input parameter directly and then forward that to you calculations method etc.